# Constructors in Struct with multiple tag name (C++)

Tags: c++, struct

I have a Structure which has two tag names, defined as follows :

```
typedef struct A
{
   blah1;
   blah2;
}B;
```

How do I define constructor for the above structure to satisfy objects created with tag A as well as tag B?

Comment: In C, you don't define a constructor. In C++, you have to use the class name to declare/define the constructor, and there's rarely a good reason to add a `typedef`.

Comment: Michael Walz, this does compile.

Comment: Mike, let's say I'm working on some legacy code that I need to modify to have a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor has to be declared using the class name `A`, not any other alias. It will be used for any objects of this type, whether they are declared using the class name or an alias.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put it in `A` and it will be available in `B` since it's just an alias.

```
typedef struct A
{
   A();
   blah1;
   blah2;
}B;

A::A() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Identifier `B` is not defined until the last semicolon, but the constructor must be declared inside the class (a struct is just a class starting with implicit `public:`). And inside the class its name is `A`, so you will have to declare the constructor as `A()`.

You can declare variable as `B b;` later, which will be the same as `A b;`.

Answer (score -1):

Since A and B are the same you can use either of them.

`typedef A B;` says that `B` is of type `A`.

```
void test(B obj); //Is valid
void test(struct A obj); //Is valid too
```

Or if you what to use a ctor:

```
typedef struct A
{
   blah1;
   blah2;

   A() 
   {
        //ctor code here
   }
}B;
```

Comment: No, constructor declarations have to use the class name.

Comment: Only `A();` will be a valid constructor declaration.

Comment: While `void test(struct A obj);` is indeed valid, there's no need for the `struct` keyword in C++ (unlike in C): `void test(A obj);` is valid too, and usually prefered.

Comment: Indeed in C++ it is valid but he used C like definition so I assumed he is coding in C.